# C# eqivalent of rest client

Tags: c#, java, rest

Here is java code of rest client. I am having problems creating.
  How create C# eqivalent on this client? I need some examples

```
public class RestServiceClient {    

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:9080/PPAUploadDocRestService/rest/uploadDocument";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                    addDocument();

    }

    public static void addDocument() {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(BASE_URL);

            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();  

            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File("C:/projects/Db2PpaPpacardsppastages.xsd")); 
            reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);

            reqEntity.addPart("fileName", new StringBody("Db2PpaPpacardsppastages.xsd"));

            reqEntity.addPart("processId", new StringBody("2872"));

            reqEntity.addPart("document", new StringBody(generateDocument()));
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);          

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String generateDocument() {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.put("docNum", "NickDoc");
        object.put("docDate", "" + new Date().getTime());
        object.put("docTypeId", "49");
        object.put("questionId", "1728");
        object.put("description", "test by NIvanov REST");
        object.put("resolution", "");
        object.put("workGroupMembers", "");
        object.put("inDocNum", "inNickDoc");
        object.put("inDocDate", "" + new Date().getTime());
        object.put("outDocNum", "outNickDoc");
        object.put("outDocDate", "" + new Date().getTime());
        object.put("docName", "NickDocName");
        object.put("employeeId", "1");
        object.put("cardId", "647");
        object.put("bpmDocId", "");
        object.put("docCode", "TNT");

        return object.toString();
    }

}
```

I've been looking into using the `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` objects. It's true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the following links
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17449/Send-a-content-type-multipart-form-data-request-fr
or http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2009/12/16/posting-multipartform-data-using-.net-webrequest.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are opensource libraries available, Please look at the following link,

http://restsharp.org/